# std::move is passing by reference instead of calling move constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm trying to wrap my head around move semantics in c++.
I created a small class to help me understand what is going on,
I deleted the `copy` and `move` assignment operators to keep things simple.

```cpp
using namespace std;

struct Bar {
    Bar(std::string a) : message{a} { cout << "default constructor" << endl; };

    Bar(const Bar& other) { cout << "copy constructor" << endl; };
    Bar(Bar&& other) noexcept { cout << "move constructor" << endl; };

    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other) = delete; //copy assignment
    Bar& operator=(Bar&& other) noexcept = delete; //move assignment

    ~Bar() { cout << "destroyed" << endl; }

    std::string message;
};


void Foo(Bar&& copy) {
        cout << copy.message << endl;
        copy.message = "Goodbye world...";
}

int main() {
        Bar b{ "Hello world!" };
        Foo(std::move(b));
        cout << b.message << endl;
}
```

The output is not what I expected:

```cpp
default constructor
Hello world!
Goodbye world...
destroyed
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I'm explicitly asking for an rvalue reference in foo `void Foo(Bar&& copy)`.
But I seem to be passing the argument by reference (I'm not sure this is actually happening but it sure looks like it).

What I was expecting was the `move` constructor to be called (I'm calling `std::move` after all), but this is not the case, does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Well, an rvalue reference is, wait for it, a reference! And that's what you passed in.

Comment: It's hard to argue with that. Thanks, I experimented a bit more, the `std::move` function name made me think "something is moving, some move constructor/operator must be executing". But that's not the case. Would it be correct to say the `move` constructor only gets called when constructing a variable `Bar b { std::move(anotherBar) }` and never when passing them around between functions?

Comment: Also, I shouldn't be using `b` after calling `std::move()` on it. right?

Comment: A move constructor gets invoked when you move something, by definition. If all you're doing is passing references around, obviously no move is taking place. All the `std::move` does is give you an rvalue reference for moving. It's not a "move this object, somewhere, and hop to it!" function.

Comment: Your example code is a little confusing since the output `default constructor` is produced by a constructor other than the default. (Actually, `Bar` has no default constructor, i.e. no constructor callable without arguments.) Maybe change that constructor to output `primary constructor` or `constructor from string` or something else more accurate?

Comment: If you change `Foo` signature to accept `Bar` by value, i.e., `void Foo(Bar copy)`, then move constructor will be invoked when you call `Foo(std::move(b));`.